# Executing procedure from Visual Studio

Tags: c#, sql, .net, oracle, visual-studio

I'm trying to execute pl\sql procedure from Visual Studio. Basically what I'm trying to do is pass some parameters and using them I'm trying to insert values into a different table. The procedure uses a cursor and inserts values into a table and after that I'm deleting that table to make use of it for the next time. The table obtained using cursor needs to be finally displayed on gridbox. But the below program isn't displaying anything. Can someone help me with this?

```
DB_connect();

String x3 = "google";
String x1;
String x2;

String s1 = "delete from temp";

OracleCommand comm = new OracleCommand(s1, conn);
comm.ExecuteNonQuery();

System.Data.OracleClient.OracleCommand comm2 = new System.Data.OracleClient.OracleCommand();
String s2 = "exec cv";

comm2.CommandText = s2;
comm2.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
comm2.Parameters.Add("x", System.Data.OracleClient.OracleType.Number).Value = comboBox1.Text;
comm2.Parameters.Add("y", System.Data.OracleClient.OracleType.Number).Value = comboBox2.Text;
comm2.ExecuteNonQuery();

String s3 = "select * from temp";

OracleCommand comm3 = new OracleCommand(s3, conn);
OracleDataAdapter MyAdapter3 = new OracleDataAdapter();//adapter acts as interface btw database and dataset(which is collectio of tables)
MyAdapter3.SelectCommand = comm;

DataTable dTable3 = new DataTable();//datatable represents a single table in database 
MyAdapter3.Fill(dTable3);

dataGridView1.DataSource = dTable3;
conn.Close();
```

This is my stored procedure:

```
create or replace procedure cv(x in int, y in int, z in varchar)
as
    cursor c
    is
        select email, collegename, cgpa, compname
        from student_cv
        where (cgpa >= x and yearsofexp >= y) and compname = z;

    tem c%rowtype;

    begin
       open c;
       loop
           fetch c into tem;
           exit when c%notfound;

           insert into temp 
           values(tem.email, tem.collegename, tem.cgpa, tem.compname);
       end loop;
    end;
/
```

**Edit**:

[image]

Comment: Have you tested that the procedure actually returns any values?

Comment: my procedure is working in sql plus but I'm getting this error while executing this from visual studio

Comment: On a general note, it's better to just run a query, or a view, or even to make a function that returns an object/rowtype, or a table of objects, or even a refcursor which you can open and read. Writing temporary data just for the sake of reading it on the other side should be the last fallback.

Comment: Open your connection: `conn.Open();` **before** you execute any operations against the data store. Also it is not clear where `conn` resides. Is this a global (static) field somewhere? If so maybe there is a race condition where multiple threads are trying to open/close this connection at the same time (like a web application with multiple requests).

Answer (score 1):

If you set the type to stored procedure, all you need is the name of the stored procedure. So commandtext should be `cv` rather than `exec cv`.

-edit-

While the thing above is an issue as well, the screenshot you posted in your update suggests that the connection is not opened yet when you call `ExecuteNonQuery`.

Or maybe it is opened, but not assigned to the command. Since an application could theoretically have multiple connections, you have to tell the command which one to use. There is no global reference to the connection that the command will use implicitly. [The example given in Oracle's documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/win.111/b28375/OracleCommandClass.htm) shows how this could be done through a property, although apparently you can also set it in the constructor, which you do for connections 1 and 3 but not for connection 2. I guess there is the problem. :o)

Comment: the connection is opened in the Db_connect function

Comment: Yes, but look at the error. It says 'connection is closed'. This error is not in the stored proc, and maybe not even in the way you call the stored proc (apart from the thing I mentioned), but in the fact that your application (or your command or query to be precise) doesn't have a database connection.

Comment: no It's connected ,I checked it in data connections

Comment: And is the connection assigned to the command? Looking at the code again, it seems you're not assigning it to comm2.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is not really the "direct path", I would do it like this. Either select the table directly:

```
var s1 = "select email, collegename, cgpa, compname from student_cv 
       where (cgpa >= :x and yearsofexp >= :y) and compname = :z";
OracleCommand comm = new OracleCommand(s1, conn);
comm.Parameters.Add("x", OracleType.Number).Value = comboBox1.Text;
comm.Parameters.Add("y", OracleType.Number).Value = comboBox2.Text;
comm.Parameters.Add("z", OracleType.VarChar2).Value = "some text";

OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(comm);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

Instead `OracleDataAdapter` and `OracleDataAdapter` you can also use `OracleDataReader`:

```
OracleDataReader dr = comm.ExecuteReader();
while ( dr.Read() ) {
   // loop through the rows and process the rows one-by-one
}
dr.close();
```

The other way is to use a function or procedure like this:

```
create or replace FUNCTION cv (x in int, y in int, z in varchar2) RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR as
   res SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
   OPEN res FOR
   select email, collegename, cgpa, compname
   from student_cv
   where (cgpa >= x and yearsofexp >= y) and compname = z;

   RETURN res;
end;
```

And then call it in C# as this:

```
comm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
comm.CommandText = "BEGIN :ret := cv(:x, :y, :z); END;";
comm.Parameters.Add("x", OracleType.Number).Value = comboBox1.Text;
comm.Parameters.Add("y", OracleType.Number).Value = comboBox2.Text;
comm.Parameters.Add("z", OracleType.VarChar2).Value = "some text";
comm.Parameters.Add("ret", OracleDbType.RefCursor, ParameterDirection.ReturnValue);

OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(comm);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

Of course, you can also use `OracleDataReader` like above.

Note, I don't have a computer in front of me for any testing, so please forgive me if I did one or two typos in the code examples.

Regarding your actual error message, ensure the correct order:

1. open the connection
2. execute the command (or several commands)
3. close the connection

As `OracleConnection` implements `IDisposal` you should enclose it by `using` like this

```
using (var conn = new OracleConnection() ) {
   conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=...";
   conn.Open();
   // Code from above

   conn.Close();
}
```

`OracleDataReader` and `OracleDataAdapter` also implements `IDisposal`, so is should be also enclosed by `using`

Answer (score -4):

You may need a commit; before end; ?